# What is Dropo's purpose?

Tags: santa-claus, santa-claus-conquers-the-martians

In the famously bad film *Santa Claus Conquers the Martians*, Dropo is one of the more famous characters from that movie. He seems to be the comic relief in this already "comedic" film. But what is his purpose among the other Martians? I mean, he doesn't seem to really do anything, but everyone knows who he is. The fact that I care to ask a question about this movie concerns me.

Comment: Wikipedia identifies him as Assistant to King Kimar; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Claus_Conquers_the_Martians. That seems like a pretty high profile

Comment: He may be related to the King, but as an embarrassment have been shunted into a purely ceremonial position.

Comment: This is currently in Comet TV’s rotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kimar was the chief of the Martians and Dropo was his servant. He was basically an assistant to him and a helping hand to his wife. True that he basically does nothing in the film but at the end Santa appoints him to be the Martian Santa.

Answer (score 0):

Dropo   I read some where was a take on Drop out, as Kimar and Momar where on king martian and mom martian, maybe he was suppose to be a symbol of what lack of education turns you into, as Dropo was lazy and a clown of sorts by 60's standards maybe a beatnik take off

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question was what was his purpose _among the other Martians_, not his purpose as an element of the plot.  Even then, this answer seems to be completely speculative, and needs some sort of evidence that this theory is correct.